# insert and delete text after an Range-position in Word

Tags: ms-word, field

I have a SET-field in Word 2007. After the set-field there could be everything (text,bookmark, SET field,...). I want to add  a text (e.g. "exampletext") in between.

After this I want to delete this inserted text (but I don't want to search through the whole document).

Is there a method?

Trial 1 (it inserts it in the field - and not after the field):

```
' xStartReturn is a field
Dim myExampletext As WordApp.Range = objDoc.Range(xStartReturn.Code.End, xStartReturn.Code.End )
myExampletext.Text = "exampletext"
```

Trial 2 (leads to the problem that I don't get the Range-field to delete the exampletext afterwards):

```
xEndeReturn.insertAfter("exampletext")
```

Trial 3:

```
'xStartReturn.Code.End + 1 doesn't work.. but I found out that the "}"-Sign in the setField is +20 after xStartReturn.Code.End. Theoretical this should work - but there could be e.g. also paragraph afterwards. 
'-> I can automatically check that there is a paragraph - but why is the exampletext added **after** the paragraph?


Dim example As WordApp.Range = objDoc.Range(xStartReturn.Code.End + 20, xStartReturn.Code.End + 20) 
example.Text = "exampletext"


Dim later As WordApp.Range = objBasisvorlage_.Range(objXStartReturn.Code.End + 20, objXStartReturn.Code.End + 20 + "SDFSD".Length) 'this is wrong?!
later.Delete()
```

Comment: The reason you haven't gotten any response before now is because you tagged this with "word" instead of "ms-word". I've corrected it and you should get some action, now...

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. Since you didn't give us a minimum code with which to reproduce the problem I don't know how relevant the framework is that I used. But you should be able to follow the steps.

Watch what I do with `r_f_Code` (field code range). You can ignore/remove r_f_Result as I had that in for reference and debugging purposes.

Collapsing the field code range to its end-point leaves the range just within the field braces. Moving the starting point one character to the right puts it just outside the braces, but before anything else. (Note: I tested with two immediately adjacent SET fields.)

My code then enters some text and bookmarks it. That's the *only* way you do what you ask if what follows the SET field can be "anything". Although I suppose you could insert a Content Control - that would be uniquely identifiable if you go about it correctly...

```
Sub PositionAfterFieldCode()
    Dim f As word.Field
    Dim r_f_Code As word.Range, r_f_Result As word.Range

    For Each f In ActiveDocument.Fields
        If f.Type = wdFieldSet Then
            Set r_f_Code = f.code
            Set r_f_Result = f.result

            'Debug.Print Len(r_f_Code), r_f_Code.Text, Len(r_f_Result), r_f_Result.Text
            r_f_Code.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            r_f_Code.MoveStart wdCharacter, 1
            'r_f_Code.Select
            r_f_Code.Text = "abc"
            r_f_Code.Bookmarks.Add "AfterSet", r_f_Code
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```